# How should I clarify specifically the contents of the license (characters, format, structure, newlines) should remain unaltered?

Tags: grammar, legalese

> Permission is hereby granted to all parties to
> copy and distribute copies of this license document provided that
> the contents of the copy of the license document remains completely unaltered
> without exception in any and all circumstances.

I only care about what is in the document, **not** how it's presented (on a website, tiny font, font coloring, character encoding etc). The current phrasing seems awkward ("the contents of the copy of the license document"), and still seems to fail at conveying the idea that only the contents should remain unaltered. How can I word it instead (bonus if the wording is effective as legalese)?

P.S: Redundancy is intentional.

Comment: *Completely unaltered* is enough. "Without exception" and "in any and all circumstances" add emphasis.

Comment: @YosefBaskin What's your point?

Comment: Sorry, trying to help your request. You asked if the wording was ironclad.

Comment: I was specifically referring to if the wording coveys that "only the contents (characters, format, structure, newlines) should remain unaltered and not how its presented". Thank you though, now I have peace of mind about the other part.

Comment: I suggest you consult a lawyer if you want your phrasing to actually have legal force. I'm sure a competent lawyer *opposing* your intended sense could run rings around anything you come up with (with or without help from other users here). It's logically impossible to draw a sharp dividing line between the actual ***words*** of your text and the ***presentation*** (inclusive of all typesetting and other variables). And what if someone needs "the same" text in a different language, for example? Or even just in ***Braille*** (which you'd better allow for, to avoid legal minefields! :)

Comment: Your question and response to comments are contradictory. You seem to want the words to be unchanged, no matter how they appear. And yet you also seem to say that the appearance must be preserved: “characters, format, structure, newlines”.

Comment: @shashin-ka Thats not the appearance. Thats the contents. How and where its presented dosent matter, eg. text font, book etc

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's not a legal endeavor just drafting up a license for fun

Comment: @Anm The **contents** of a written document are the **words and their meanings**. The contents does not depend on any formatting, character type style, visual structure, or line justification (with newlines or carriage returns). Changing any or all of these variables _has no effect on the meaning of the document_. You appear to be describing the **visual aspects** of a document, not its words or meaning. The only way your description makes sense is if you are discussing an _image of a document_, which is not to be changed.